# Grammar with gerund or Infinitive

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

He tried ________ (work) in a newspaper firm but he still wasn't satisfied.

These variants are wrong:
working / to work / work / having worked

What is the correct form of (work)?

Comment: Why do you think all of those are wrong?

Comment: This is my home task (on the website) and I can check only if my answer right or wrong, but no keys.

This is the link https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Gerund_or_Infinitive/Advanced_gerunds_and_infinitives_kc1581738sc

Comment: I think that website is broken. "Working" and "to work" are valid answers, and I can't think of any other forms, like passive, perfect, continuous etc. that fit.

Comment: **-Ing** should be the answer

Comment: Thank you! I having my English class on Wednesday, I really want to know the correct answer. Hope my teacher will explain what is the correct variant.

Comment: The most salient verb form is "working".

Comment: @gotube The correct answer is  (NOT 'to work') There is a difference between 'tried working' and 'tried to work'. He tried working means he worked. But He tried to work means he could not work.

Comment: If you *try **doing** something*, the implication is that you were in fact *able* to do it, even if this didn't achieve what you wanted. For example, *I tried driving to work, but the traffic was so bad I was late*. If you *try **to do** something*, the implication is you weren't actually able to do it *at all* (or at least, not *properly*). For example, *I tried **to drive** to work, but my car wouldn't start*.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think those are all wrong? The first three are right and commonly used and the fourth is unusual but valid.

"He tried working in a newspaper ..." This is exactly what most Americans would say. It means he got a job at a newspaper and tried it out.

"He tried to work in a newspaper ..." Also valid but a little ambiguous. Most readers would understand it to mean that he tried to get a job at a newspaper but couldn't get such a job. Or that he got the job but couldn't perform the required tasks. It could also mean the same as "he tried working".

"He tried work in a newspaper ..." Also valid and same as "working". Technically different grammar. "He tried working ..." means he attempted the task. "Working" is a verb. In "He tried work ...", "work" is a noun, so you're saying he tried the thing instead of he tried the action. In this example both mean the same thing. There are many words in English that can't be used as both a verb and a noun. Like you could say, "He tried eating fruit ..." but you can't say "He tried eat fruit ..." because "eat" cannot be used as a noun.

"He tried having worked at a newspaper ..." "Having [verb]" is usually used to mean that some pre-condition was met. Like, "Having completed all graduation requirements, George was given a diploma." So it's possible here. "He tried having worked ... but ..." He met the condition -- working in a newspaper -- but he still wasn't satisfied. But it sounds awkward to me. Maybe there some technical grammar rule that it breaks that I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the test has an error in it. I was curious (and procrastinating from my work) so I looked at the javascript source code, and found the answer it was expecting for question 17 was `getting`. Obviously very wrong (`getting` is not a form of `work`) - the correct answer should have been `working`, as others have pointed out.

[image: screenshot of broken test with one correct (but wrong) answer]

My guess is that the answers text missed out a slash, and `getting` was actually supposed to be one answer option for the previous question (16).

Comment: I think you're mistaken. As so often happens with TEFL tests set by non-native Anglophones, it's a rubbish test - because ***both answers are perfectly valid.*** Well, actually, ***getting*** is somewhat more "likely" in the real world than ***to get***. In principle they could mean different things, but in practice *but he still wasn't satisfied* implies they both carry exactly the same meaning anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you think I'm mistaken about? I just posted the answer the test code would have marked as correct, whilst pointing out that (obviously) "getting" is not a form of "work"... I also pointed out that this was probably supposed to be an *option* for question 16. You seem to be saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: Your answer *appears* to say that ***getting*** is not a "correct" answer. The truth is that ***all options are syntactically valid*** - it's just that as @Geoff points out below, it's not easy to come up with a context where ***having worked*** would work (in a way that makes sense with *...but he still wasn't satisfied*)

Comment: My answer is quite clearly saying *getting* is an incorrect answer for question 17. The test asks you to enter a form of "work", but marks "getting" as correct for **question 17**.

Comment: I have edited my answer for even more clarity. I invite you to re-read it and then remove your downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Correct: He tried **working**...

**Try + ing**- do something as an **experiment** or **test**

[ Try to work- attempt to work ]